# C# XAML Universal Apps - Change StackPanel's width as TextBoxes inside grow

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a few `TextBoxes` inside a `StackPanel` like this:

```
...
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBox Text="1"></TextBox>
  <TextBox Text="1"></TextBox>
  <TextBox Text="1"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
...
```

I would like the `StackPanel` to grow as the `TextBox`es are typed into, but instead, the `TextBox`es wrap as more text is added.

How can I make the `StackPanel` to grow as the `TextBox`es are typed into?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your solution it works for me.
But you could try to add the property `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` to each `TextBox` or create a `Style`.

Or you could use instead of a `StackPanel` a `Grid` which does also work

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefiniton Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefiniton Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefiniton Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution works! Apparently I set TextWrapping to Wrap.